# Silverlight inotifypropertychanged

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Can any one explain in detail how it works with a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of articles that should help:

- http://www.silverlightshow.net/tips/How-to-implement-INotifyPropertyChanged-interface.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLListVsOCollections.aspx
- http://www.designerwpf.com/2009/04/30/inotifypropertychanged-snippets-and-why-you-should-use-these-instead-of-dependencyproperties/

HTH!
Chris